# chef light weight resource provider not working

Tags: chef-infra

I have created a LWRP (my first time) but it doesn't seem to work as required. I am not sure if I am missing something or did something wrong. The opscode documentation is horrible. I have show my code below:

**Provider**

```
puts "FOO"

def restart_process
  @svc = Chef::Resource::RestartProcesses.new(new_resource.name)
  Chef::Log.debug("Restarting services according to the box")
  notifies :run, resources(:execute => 'restart-storm')
end

puts "BAR"

action :restart do

  execute 'restart-process' do
    command <<-EOH
      echo "-------Executing restart process--------"
      #Some bash code
    EOH
  end
end
```

**Resource**

```
actions :restart

attribute :name, :kind_of => String, :name_attribute => true

def initialize(*args)
  super
  @action = :restart
end
```

**Recipe from which the resource is called**

```
template "#{install_dir}/####Something" do
  source "someSource.erb"
  variables(
    ###Some variables
  )

  notifies :run, 'nameOfCookbook_nameOfResource[process]'
end

nameOfCookbook_nameOfResource "process" do
  action :nothing
end
```

The chef output shows **FOO BAR** but it doesn't print anything inside my *bash* script. So it doesn't run the bash. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to tell the instance to run the action :restart

like

```
restart = nameOfCookbook_nameOfResource "process" do
  action :nothing
end

restart.run_action(:restart)
```

I know you've set the initialize to say restart but I think passing action :nothing overwrites that so either force it to run when you want by following the above example or within the template part notify the actual action you want as such

```
notifies :restart
```

By running this myself I saw an action of :nothing executed on the resource only. Not the default behaviour which in my case would have been :stop

By changing the notification to :stop it had the expected behaviour.

My understanding from the log is you have told your resource to run but it's action is :nothing so it does nothing.

Comment: Edited. notifies :restart instead of notifies :run should work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your

```
notifies :run, 'nameOfCookbook_nameOfResource[process]'
```

in template actually scheduled to run. (Using debug output, for example). Because if file already exists there, nothing will be done and so the restart too.